# Oracle SQL select all fields except

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Is there a statement that allows you to select all fields from all tables in my schema with the exception of other fields?

The statement I'm using to select everything and create a view is:

```
CREATE VIEW NEW_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES
```

I want the view to `select *` from all the user tables except primary key fields such as CUSTOMER_ID and PRODUCT_ID